# Jackson: Serialise POJO using class method

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I know I can use `(new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(this, ObjectNode.class)` to serialise given object to `JSON`. Is there a way to tell the lib to use a method inside that class to serialise it ?

My classes:

```
interface A {
  ObjectNode toJSON();
}

abstract class Tokens {
  Map<String, String> tokends;
}

class Foo extends Tokens implements A {
  private long id;
  private Bar bar;

  // Constructors, getters & setters...

  @Override
  public ObjectNode toJSON() {
    ObjectNode node = (new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(this, ObjectNode.class);
    tokens.forEach(node::put);

    return node;
  }
}

class Bar extends Tokens implements A {
  private long id;

  // Constructors, getters & setters...

  @Override
  public ObjectNode toJSON() {
    ObjectNode node = (new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(this, ObjectNode.class);
    tokens.forEach(node::put);

    return node;
  }
}
```

Now if I call `(new A()).toJSON()` I will get:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "bar": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "token1": "...",
  "token2": "...:,
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "bar": {
    "id": 2,
    "token3": "...",
    "token4": "..."
  },
  "token1": "...",
  "token2": "...:,
}
```

I understand that this happens because the first method modifies the serialised class but is not called by jackson when it goes into child objects.

Is there a way to tell jaskson to use `toJSON` method to create the child with tokens as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a slightly different approach, [@JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) provides a way to include the keys of the `tokens` map directly in the parent JSON:

```
abstract class Tokens {
    Map<String, String> tokens = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getTokens() {
        return tokens;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addToken(String key, String value) {
        tokens.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Then such as:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo);
```

returns:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "bar" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "token3" : "three",
    "token4" : "four"
  },
  "token1" : "one",
  "token2" : "two"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much I'm not sure how I missed that annotation. Spent whole bloody day trying to figure this one out. Thank you so very much.

Comment: I will award you the bounty, just have to wait 20h for some reason.

Comment: It's part of the process to ensure enough time for a fully complete answer to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Jackson annotation `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue` on your `toJSON()` method. From the javadoc :

> Marker annotation similar to javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue that indicates that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means signature must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance. Usually value will be of a simple scalar type (String or Number), but it can be any serializable type (Collection, Map or Bean).

Comment: Annotating `Foo`, `Bar` or both classes `toJSON` method with `@JsonValue` yields nothing than I do `foo.toJSON().toString()` and I get nothing back.